# What is this error? "no matching function for call to 'foreach(std::array<int, 4>&, void(&)(int))"

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

I created a `foreach()` function, and it should print values of an array, but it tells me this:

> no matching function for call to 'foreach(std::array<int, 4>&, void(&)(int))'

And also:

> mismatched types 'unsigned int' and 'long unsigned int'

But when I try to use `vector`s instead of arrays, or on line 11 use `template<unsigned int N>` instead of `unsigned int`, if I use `long unsigned int`, it works fine.

So, why do I need to use `long unsigned int`?

And what does the "no matching function" error mean with arrays?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<array>

typedef void(*func)(int);

void print(int value) {
    std::cout << "value is : " << value << std::endl;
}

template<unsigned int N>
void foreach(std::array<int, N>& values, func print) {
    int value;
    for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        value = values[i];
        print(value);
    }
}

int main() {

    std::array<int, 4> arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    foreach(arr, print);

    return 0;
}
```

With vectors:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

typedef void(*func)(int);

void print(int value) {
    std::cout << "value is : " << value << std::endl;
}

void foreach(std::vector<int>& values, func print) {
    int value;
    for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        value = values[i];
        print(value);
    }
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    foreach(v, print);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `std::for_each()`? And if it's the pair of iterators, why not just wrap it?

Comment: `template<size_t N>` seems like a better fit for `void foreach`

Answer (score 4):

The template for `std::array` does not take an `unsigned int`, it takes a [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), which may or may not (probably not) be defined as `unsigned int`:

```cpp
template<size_t N>
void foreach(std::array<int, N>& values, func print);
```

A better option is to make your function be container-agnostic instead, by passing it iterators instead of the actual container, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

typedef void(*func)(int);

void print(int value) {
    std::cout << "value is : " << value << std::endl;
}

template<typename Iter>
void foreach(Iter begin, Iter end, func print) {
    while (begin != end) {
        print(*begin);
        ++begin;
    }
}

int main() {

    std::array<int, 4> arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    foreach(arr.begin(), arr.end(), print);

    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    foreach(v.begin(), v.end(), print);

    return 0;
}
```

Not only does this allow the function to work with multiple containers, but also with different element types, if you change the `print` parameter to be a template as well, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

void printInt(int value) {
    std::cout << "value is : " << value << std::endl;
}

void printStr(const std::string &value) {
    std::cout << "value is : " << value << std::endl;
}

template<typename Iter, typename Callable>
void foreach(Iter begin, Iter end, Callable print) {
    while (begin != end) {
        print(*begin);
        ++begin;
    }
}

int main() {

    std::array<int, 4> arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    foreach(arr.begin(), arr.end(), printInt);

    std::vector<std::string> v = { "hello", "world", "joe", "smoe" };
    foreach(v.begin(), v.end(), printStr);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the exact strategy that standard algorithms use, such as [`std::for_each()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) (which you should be using instead of writing your own) <sup>1</sup>, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::array<int, 4> arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
        [](int value) { std::cout << "value is : " << value << std::endl; }
    );

    std::vector<std::string> v = { "hello", "world", "joe", "smoe" };
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [](const std::string &value) { std::cout << "value is : " << value << std::endl; }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>1: C++20 introduced a new [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) that has algorithms to act on whole containers.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Because the second template parameter for [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is `std::size_t`, not `unsigned int`. Compiler cannot infer the convertion between types in template function. And it just happens that `std::size_t` in your compiler is a typedef on `long unsigned int`, so that's what it suggests.

You can make it work in two ways:

1. Change the template type to `std::size_t`
2. Provide template parameter explicitly when calling:

   `foreach<4>(v, print);`